# composer exclude-from-classmap not working

Tags: php, laravel, npm, composer-php, autoload

so I have the following in my composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database", "app/path1"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
          "/app/path1/Front/"
        ]
    },
```

and yet when i run `composer dump-autoload -o` it would still complain about

```
  [Symfony\Component\Finder\Exception\AccessDeniedException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:/app\path1\Front\
  node_modules\babel-preset-react\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-react-j
  sx\node_modules\babel-helper-builder-react-jsx\node_modules\babel-types\nod
  e_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\babel-code-frame\node_modules\chalk,C
  :/app\path1\Front\node_modules\babel-preset-react\node_modu
  les\babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx\node_modules\babel-helper-builder-reac
  t-jsx\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\bab
  el-code-frame\node_modules\chalk): The system cannot find the path specifie
  d. (code: 3)






  [UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:/app\path1\Front\
  node_modules\babel-preset-react\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-react-j
  sx\node_modules\babel-helper-builder-react-jsx\node_modules\babel-types\nod
  e_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\babel-code-frame\node_modules\chalk,C
  :/app\path1\Front\node_modules\babel-preset-react\node_modu
  les\babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx\node_modules\babel-helper-builder-reac
  t-jsx\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\bab
  el-code-frame\node_modules\chalk): The system cannot find the path specifie
  d. (code: 3)
```

Which means that it is not really excluding /app/path1/Front/

What am I doing wrong and how can I exclude that directory so that it won't return those exceptions

Comment: Did you try the same config without the leading slash?

Comment: It is not clear what problems you are trying to solve? Can you give us a great example of a project?